# How can setting Checkpoints for running at aperiod of time at gem5?

Tags: gem5

I run this configuration: I need to take checkpoints every 10msec, is that correct, if the frequency is 1GH?

```html
./build/ALPHA/gem5.opt configs/example/fs.py --num-cpus=16\
--cpu-type=atomic --mem-size=1GB --checkpoint-dir=/home/xx/gem5/m5out \
--script=run_scripts/vips_16c_simsmall.rcS \ 
-- take checkpoints=200000000,1000000
--kernel=/home/xx/gem5/full_system_images_ALPHA/binaries/vmlinux_2.6.27-gcc_4.3.4 \
--disk-image=/home/xx/gem5/full_system_images_ALPHA/disks/linux-parsec-2-1-m5-with-test-inputs.img --checkpoint-at-end
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would just try to verify it by writing a shell script that prints hello every 10ms and then count the number of checkpoints to see if it matches.